# AVVideopreviewlayer preserving aspect ratio

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Hi I am developing app where I wanted to keep max resolution for camera feed i.e 4:3 aspect ratio in most cases.

When I use video gravity .aspectResize for preview layer which have full screen as frame, video gets shown by adding black bars on top and bottom. I assume this is because camera try to fit max resolution 4:3 on 16:9 device.

Now I wanted to achieve same max resolution but wanted to start preview layer from zero point on top. Meaning I don’t wanted to show black bar on top rather I am okay camera to adjust from bottom by adding extra height for black bars. Is there any way to achieve this?

My assumption is if I use .resizeAspectFill it will not allow me to use max resolution 4:3.
Please make me correct if that’s not true.

Comment: No, `resizeAspectFill` shouldn't affect the max resolution 4:3

Comment: @aheze how do I make sure that? I mean is there way to check?

Comment: Any suggestion on this?